# Angular boostrap datetimepicker can't disable past dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to disable al lthe past dates from an angular boostrap datetimepicker. I found that in order to do that I should use date-disabled but honestly, I don't understand it and it doesn't work either.

```
<datetimepicker class="calendar-format"
                data-ng-model="data.date"
                date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)"></datetimepicker>

this.isDisabledDate = function(currentDate, mode) {
  return mode === 'day' &&
    (currentDate.getDay() === 0 || currentDate.getDay() === 6);
};
```

How can I make it so that it doesn't let me pick past dates?

This is what I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker

My current code, not working: plnkr.co/edit/VGTFJaVN6Y62Frmt3ksB?p=preview

ANy other ideas how to make al lthe past dates get grayed out/unable to be picked>?

I tried everything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: which directive or plugin you are using ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: @Mocktheduck did the answer resolved your issue?

Comment: No it didnt, the calendar is still not working

Comment: Can you give plnkr link?

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/VGTFJaVN6Y62Frmt3ksB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use below code to disable past dates by setting min date scope object in your JS.

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yyyy',
            startingDay: 1
    };
 $scope.opened = true;
 $scope.minDate=  new Date();//today and future dates will be enabled..
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setFullYear (maxDate.getFullYear() + 2);//enable for 2 future years.. 
 $scope.maxDate= maxDate;
```

Your HTML will look like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control selection-box"
                                id="datepicker" 
                                datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"
                                ng-model="selectedDate" is-open="opened"
                                min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate"
                                datepicker-options="dateOptions" readonly="readonly"
                                ng-change="changeDate()"
                                close-text="Close" ng-required="true" />
```

In the case of angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker, you can do it by setting min date in date options in below way in your Js

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    showWeeks: false,
    startingDay: 0
  };

    var minDate = new Date();
    minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate());
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = minDate;
```

In your HTML

```
<datetimepicker class="calendar-format" date-options="dateOptions" data-ng-model="data.date" date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)"></datetimepicker>
```

Comment: This is not using the same calendar that I'm using. I dont want my entire thing to change

Comment: Ok ! I ll update answer according to it ,this datepicker is relatively easy so I suggested it.Can u post a plunker of what you have tried.

Comment: I want to use datetimepicker from angular-boostrap. I tried using date-disabled, I tried using date-options... probably I didnt use them correctly or not, they didnt work for me. I can still pick any date

Comment: It still lets me pick past dates. They are not grayed out or anything :/

Comment: ok I tired and It's working for me ! can you gimme your plunker so I can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just put

attribute in html

```
date-options="dateOptions"
```

update your html to

```
<datetimepicker class="calendar-format" data-ng-model="data.date" date-disabled="isDisabledDate(date, mode)" date-options="dateOptions"></datetimepicker>
```

and put below code in js

```
$scope.dateOptions.minDate = new Date();
```

here is plunker of it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/s6Gm8x8ExndUj6EBYbhi?p=preview

Comment: That's the code I followed yet it doesn't work. This is what I have http://plnkr.co/edit/VGTFJaVN6Y62Frmt3ksB?p=preview

Comment: Sorry but that plunker is not working, it just display's {{ }}

Comment: I know it's not working and I don't really understand why but I just wanted to show you the code.

Comment: I have worked on it on several case, can you create any example in fiddle if there is any issue then I can help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to dynamically disable dates based on selection, you can use the min and max attributes and watchers.

**JS**

```
$scope.endDateBeforeRender = endDateBeforeRender
$scope.endDateOnSetTime = endDateOnSetTime
$scope.startDateBeforeRender = startDateBeforeRender
$scope.startDateOnSetTime = startDateOnSetTime

function startDateOnSetTime () {
  $scope.$broadcast('start-date-changed');
}

function endDateOnSetTime () {
  $scope.$broadcast('end-date-changed');
}

function startDateBeforeRender ($dates) {
  if ($scope.dateRangeEnd) {
    var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeEnd);

    $dates.filter(function (date) {
      return date.localDateValue() >= activeDate.valueOf()
    }).forEach(function (date) {
      date.selectable = false;
    })
  }
}

function endDateBeforeRender ($view, $dates) {
  if ($scope.dateRangeStart) {
    var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeStart).subtract(1, $view).add(1, 'minute');

    $dates.filter(function (date) {
      return date.localDateValue() <= activeDate.valueOf()
    }).forEach(function (date) {
      date.selectable = false;
    })
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
     <div class="dropdown form-group">
    <label>Start Date</label>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownStart" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"
       href="#">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="dateRangeStart">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeStart"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed' }"
                        data-on-set-time="startDateOnSetTime()"
                        data-before-render="startDateBeforeRender($dates)"></datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown form-group">
    <label>End Date</label>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownEnd" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#"
       href="#">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="dateRangeEnd">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeEnd"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownEnd', renderOn: 'start-date-changed' }"
                        data-on-set-time="endDateOnSetTime()"
                        data-before-render="endDateBeforeRender($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate)"></datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use <datetimepicker> tag

Comment: i have edited my answer, try it out!! it worked for me long time back

Comment: This is code that I've seen before and tested. It breaks my entire app. Why is it so long? Why the dropdown? I need a calendar

Comment: This answer completely copied from [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)....